# Full path while zipping?

Tags: linux, zip

I have the following files:

```
~/Dir1/file1.txt

~/Dir2/file2.txt
```

Then I use the following command:

```
cd ~
zip out.zip /Dir1/file1.txt /Dir2/file2.txt
```

In the out.zip I can see two directories (dir1 and dir2) but want only these two files (file1.txt and file2.txt) were in the root of out.zip!

I thought the `-D` option is what I need, but it doesn't work.

Comment: shouldn't you be using Dir1/file1.txt Dir2/file2.txt instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `-j` option is what you want:

```
zip -j out.zip ~/Dir1/file1.txt ~/Dir2/file2.txt
```

From the man page:

```
-j     Store just the name of a saved file (junk the path), 
       and do not store directory names. By default, zip 
       will store the full path (relative to the current path).
```